# Why WebSphere 7 can't find defined "working directory"?

Tags: websphere-7, ibm-rad

When creating new WebSphere 7 server profile, I defined Working directory value using the admin console (Application servers > server1 > Process definition) as following :

`C:\workspace7\Myproject\workingdirectory`

This folder contains some config files (.properties)

When I start server it works but with this message in system out:

Properties file undefined : 
`C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\myprofile\bin\Myproject\Myproject.properties`

In fact, it should point to :

`C:\workspace7\Myproject\workingdirectory\Myproject\Myproject.properties`

This problem conduct to fail when executing the application on the server.

So, have you an idea about why it's not taking the good path of working directory from the defined property in server profile?

Environment: WebSphere 7 & RAD 8

kind regards,

Comment: Are you sure you are staring the new profile you created? 
If you right-click the server you are starting in RAD and choose "Properties", and select "Websphere Application Server" What is the Profile Directory set to?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if I sound like someone from Support, but I was not able to recreate your problem. I used RAD version 8 with a WebSphere Application Server version 7. After profile start the process clearly ran in the specified working directory. I checked it using lsof and an example application. Like Terrell already asked, are you sure about the profile settings?

Two other thing you should consider.

Personally, I would not develop a piece of software that is so dependent on the current working directory as it sounds in your question. I would rather use Java System Property settings to point to a configuration directory or something similiar.

Secondly, if you use RAD with a configured WAS (or Tomcat or whatever) server profile, make sure you check the server specific settings inside RAD (context menu of the profile). For example, per default RAD uses its own deployment path for a server profile when it deploys an application to the respective server.